# PHP Login with another server database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, authentication, mysqli

How to login with another sever database and list some content from that database ?

what are the required settings for that?

Comment: you wrote a lot of tags including mssql and mysql. What sql server are you trying to access?

Comment: actually i meant mysql

Comment: then look Elias answer. Beside this,make sure that firewall on server enable 3306 port and also that user in db can connect from any host.

Answer (score 2):

With PDO, you can easily connect to two different databases/servers in the same script.

```
<?php
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST2.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE2.';charset=utf8', DB_USER2, DB_PASS2);

//Select something from database 1      
$results = $db1->query("SELECT * FROM table");

//Select something from database 2
$results2 = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM another_table");
```

If you want to connect to a server outside of localhost - remember to open the firewall and add your server's IP to access hosts.

Comment: No actually my website is hosted in one sever and i want to access database from another server

Comment: Totally different question!!!!  Update your post accordingly.

Comment: NOT a different question! just need to say that you enter the DB settings for Database Server.

Comment: I had actually written "If you want to connect to a server outside of localhost - remember to open the firewall and add your server's IP to access hosts." below the post, but someone else made an edit while I entered it, so it was overwritten. It's re-added now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to connect to mysql db...
Check [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) and instead of localhost you add the remote host.
Also you should check that the firewall of that server allows incoming connections to the port that mysql is running e.g. 3306

Answer (score -1):

if you connect with mysql_connect just do

`$con2  = mysql_connect(host,user,pass,true);` the true the end tells php to create a new resource

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated and should be avoided. Use MySQLi or PDO (as above) instead.

Comment: depreciated, but not wrong. +1 Elias answer